# Visual Basic in Word - Extra form appearing before start of main form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-word

I have taken over development of a tool that helps our company fill out standardized contracts. It is a Visual Basic form in Word.

There is one very small issue left, but it is annoying.
So we have a form that starts when a new document created from the template and this works just fine, however before the form is presented to the user, another form(at least that's what it looks like) appears. It have a text input field and an OK and a Cancel button. The title of the window is **Referencenumber**.

I have searched all the code for this title and can not find it. It also doesn't matter what you put in the input field, it is not put in the final document. And it also doesn't matter whether you press OK or Cancel.

Could you help figure what it is or how I can remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here and guessing it's an ASK or FILLIN field in the document (probably ASK since you're not seeing the result in the document).

Press Alt+F9 to toggle on the field code display then, if you don't see { ASK [other stuff here ] } immediately you can do a Find on: ^d ASK

ASK writes the user input to a bookmark which can then be used (referenced) elsewhere on by the object model. You should be able to simply delete the field and request the input in your form. But do watch out for REF fields referencing the bookmark information. Ctrl+A, F9 (update all the fields in the main story) should show up an ERROR! if the field (and its bookmark) are deleted.

If it's not one of these fields then it could be something popping up from another add-in. But if that's the case you'd see it with other documents, as well...

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a FILLIN. I didn't even know about these.

Comment: Interesting, then, that you didn't see your input in the document... Yeah, these were (are) the simple way for useres to create "forms" and pre-date form fields and VBA (i.e. been around for over 20 years).

Comment: I think it is because that particular place might be overwritten at some later point in the code. But thanks a lot for the help!